# Why are XVisuals repeated in xdpyinfo

Tags: x11, xlib

Looking into my output of xdpyinfo, I see a lot of Visuals of the exact same characteristics repeated. Why are they repeated?

For example,

```
visual:
visual id:    0x6e
class:    TrueColor
depth:    32 planes
available colormap entries:    256 per subfield
red, green, blue masks:    0xff0000, 0xff00, 0xff
significant bits in color specification:    8 bits

visual:
visual id:    0x6f
class:    TrueColor
depth:    32 planes
available colormap entries:    256 per subfield
red, green, blue masks:    0xff0000, 0xff00, 0xff
significant bits in color specification:    8 bits
```

0x6e and 0x6f are exactly the same.

A related question: A visual already has a concept of depth, so why is it required to pass both a depth and a visual to XCreateWindow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The two visuals are not necessarily exactly the same. They may have different GLX properties. Run `glxinfo -v` to see them.
2. <s>The depth of the visual is the maximal depth. My screen for instance has many visuals, all of them are of depth 24 or 32. The X server supports more depths, in my case 24, 1, 4, 8, 15, 16, and 32. In a visual of a given depth you can create a window of a smaller depth.</s> The preceding is wrong. The depth of the visual is the only depth it supports. One cannot create a window of any other depth.

Comment: I didn't realize that depth of a Visual is the "maximal depth".

Comment: @reetone This is apparently wrong, see update (a bit late I know).

Comment: Good point with that `glxinfo` and additional GLX buffers & stuff. Looks like back in 2011 one could learn something useful on StackOverflow after all...